# What does the userid parameter do in tag badge links?

Tags: support, badges, hyperlinks

Clicking on a badge from your profile gives sends you to a URL with a `userid` parameter. That parameter causes the badge page to list all of the questions that the user has earned that badge for, for example:

> https://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened?userid=31582

That same `userid` parameter exists for tag badges, but (since a tag badge doesn't apply to a single question) the list of links is irrelevant, so no additional information is added compared to the bare URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/badges/90/ruby-on-rails?userid=31582

Should tag badges list personalised information with a `userid` parameter available? For example, it could list the date the badge was awarded (I think tag badges can only be awarded once at each level?)